# How to expand GitHub Actions steps `run` strings?

Tags: bash, github-actions

I'd like to make sure all my shell scripts are properly linted using `shellcheck`. One of the problems is that a lot of shell code is wrapped inside GitHub Actions workflows (`.github/workflows/*.yml`), for example:

```yaml
- name: Install Conda environment packages
  run: foo install bar="${{ env.GDAL_VERSION }}" "${{ matrix.baz }}"
```

`yq --nul-output '.jobs.*.steps[].run | select( . != null )' .github/workflows/*.yml` will get the raw YAML values for these, but the command as written in the YAML is not valid Bash - it's got GitHub Actions-specific `${{ NAME }}` syntax in there. I can't easily replace all such variable references with dummy values, so the better alternative would be to get the command as actually run by GitHub. Is this possible?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you want to replace with dummy values you can pipe the commands through this perl command: `echo 'your_shell_code' | perl -p -e 's/\$\{\{.+?\}\}//g'`

Comment: In general I don't think it will be possible to use the "real" values that GitHub would use, for example, actions can be run manually, and may have explicit inputs and you won't know what the inputs are unless the user provides them. Another issue is that you'll need to make sure your linter has access to secrets (and it's probably more secure to use dummy values for secrets anyway)

Comment: [actionlint](https://github.com/rhysd/actionlint) runs ShellCheck on `run` steps; it [handles](https://github.com/rhysd/actionlint/blob/1ed1a83bf43b9a7d8795976cb47def2480388139/rule_shellcheck.go#L120-L157) `${{ ... }}` by replacing it with underscores. Side note: often, it's safer to set these values in the environment of the step instead of expanding them directly. And lastly, `${{ env.BLAH }}` is just `$BLAH`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Could you post that as an answer? It does sound like exactly the sort of thing I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Benjamin W. mentioned, the actionlint not only runs ShellCheck on the run steps but also handles the GitHub Actions-specific `${{ ... }}` syntax by replacing it with underscores, and it's worth noting that setting values in the environment of the step is often considered safer than expanding them directly, so, instead of using `${{ env.VARIABLE_NAME }}`, you can simply use `$VARIABLE_NAME`.

first of all install `actionlint` and `ShellCheck` in your development environment and run `actionlint` on your GitHub Actions workflow files `(.github/workflows/*.yml)` to perform linting checks on the run steps, then try to verify that any GitHub Actions-specific syntax, such as `${{ ... }}`, is replaced with underscores by `actionlint` and finally consider setting values in the environment of the step using `$VARIABLE_NAME` rather than expanding them directly with `${{ env.VARIABLE_NAME }}`!